Redirect to Page via Header.jsp
I am trying to figure out how to Redirect back to my Search Results from a JavaScript Function: On the Header of the JSP that is show for a given search Result there is a 'Return to Results List' link that one can click to return to the search results. Since changing to the ModelAndView Controller format it seems like this Return link is no longer function and now just returns a Blank White Page. I've tried tinkering with the underlying controllers and debugging through some of it but I am not quite sure why It is blank. I think I am misunderstanding something here, but I'm not sure what.
searchResultHeading.jsp is the jsp that has the header inside of it that contains the link in question
        <%if(ApplicationBean.getBizActivityAuthorizations().ResultBasicInfo() && !ApplicationBean.isInExternalAppContext()) { %>
            &nbsp;| <a href="javaScript:returnToResultList();" class=sm>Return to Result list</a>
        <% } %>     
        </td>
    </tr>

Header.jsp is another jsp that contains a ton of common stuff as well as functions. The returnToResultList Function is inside there
function returnToResultList()
{
    <%if(ApplicationBean.isSearchResultsAvailable()){
    %>
        gotoSearchResults(document.userSelection);
    <%
    }else if(ApplicationBean.isMarketingListAvailable()){
    %>
        gotoListParticipants();
    <%
    }%> 
}
function gotoSearchResults(searchForm)
{
    searchForm.userAction.value = "<%=myLiterals.USER_ACTION_RETURN_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS_PAGE%>";
    searchForm.action="/mySite/GlobalNavigationController";
    searchForm.submit();
    return true;
}

The GlobalNavigationController.java itself is below which is where I redirect to various controllers who display their JSPs.
@Controller
public class GlobalNavigationController {

@Autowired
private CustomerListController customerListController;

@RequestMapping(path="/GlobalNavigationController", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
   public ModelAndView doGet(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception
    {
        SiteBean myBean = new myBean();
        try
        {
            RequestMapper.MapToBean(req,myBean);
            if (myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_1))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if(myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_2))
            {
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processSideNav();
                GlobalNavigationUCService.resetDisPlayOrder();
                return maintainController.doGet(session, req, res);
            }
            else if (myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_3))
            {
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processSideNavInitiateSearch();
                GlobalNavigationUCService.resetDisPlayOrder();
                return SearchController.doGet(session, req, res);
            }
            else if(myBean.getUserAction().equalsIgnoreCase(myLiteral.USER_ACTION_4))
            {
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processSideNavInitiateSearch();
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processTabsGoToResults();
                GlobalNavigationUCService.resetDisPlayOrder();
                return ProfileController.doGet(session,req,res);
            }
            else if (myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_RETURN_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS_PAGE))
            {
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processTabsGoToResults();
                return customerListController.doGet(session, req, res);
            }

EDIT:
Upon looking at the F12 Network Details I see that the Payload to the GlobalNav is not passing the new userAction being defined by the JavaScript. But I am defining the new UserAction in the function. Perhaps something is not carrying forward from how I setup the Model and View Structure?


Your code might throw exceptions. Catch it and add a stacktrace to the question.

@RomanC Currently there is nothing in the Console regarding any exceptions. I can try adding a Try-Catch to the JavaScript function and see if that is returning an exception and not reporting it.

I debugged it with some Try-Catches in the Javascript Function(s) and didn't find any errors. I am thinking like I edited the above, the UserAction in the form is not being properly passed and the redirect is leading to nothing happening.

Did you debug a white blank page? The error is published there.

I have try-catches in the GlobalNavController and the SearchList Controller that the GlobalNav should be redirecting to.. I placed Try-Catches in the Javascript Function to print errors to the console. I didn't see any exceptions in the network tab of my browser or the console of my IDE at any point of me re-running the code and testing the page. The only thing that looked off was in the GlobalNavServlet in the networking tab, the userAction doesn't match the literal the javascript function is referencing. the Literal being assigned to the userAction should be: 'returnToSearchResultsPage'

These literals are not available in your code.

At the top of the Header.jsp we're importing the literals file:

This seemed to work prior to the changes to the ModelAndView-Controller structure.

Nobody knows it, consider making [MCVE].

I figured out what was occurring:
When the migration to a Spring MVC structure was performed, this userAction was thought to be deprecated due to the original functionality being deprecated. The result was the Redirect was being returned null. The flag the JSP was referencing when calling function is set site-wide to always be True.
As a result, we weren't hitting the Javascript function inside of the if-condition shown above but instead this function inside the else:
function gotoListParticipants()
{
    userSelection.userAction.value="<%=myLiterals.USER_ACTION_REVIEW_MARKETING_LIST_PARTICIPANTS%>";
    userSelection.action= "/mySite/GlobalNavigationServlet";
    userSelection.submit();
    return true;        
}

To fix it I implemented the call to the CustomerListController if the userAction is set to USER_ACTION_REVIEW_MARKETING_LIST_PARTICIPANTS.
@Controller
public class GlobalNavigationController {

@Autowired
private CustomerListController customerListController;

@RequestMapping(path="/GlobalNavigationController", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
   public ModelAndView doGet(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception
    {
        SiteBean myBean = new myBean();
        try
        {
            RequestMapper.MapToBean(req,myBean);
            if (myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_1))
            {
                return null;
            }
            else if(myBean.getUserAction().equals(myLiterals.USER_ACTION_REVIEW_MARKETING_LIST_PARTICIPANTS))
            {
                GlobalNavigationUCService.processTabsGoToSearch();
                if(applicationServlet.getUserContext(req).getSearchResults() == null) {
                    GlobalNavigationUCService.resetCustomerDetailsInUserContext();
                }
                return customerListController.doGet(session, req, res);
            }

